# Inject test data to Junit reports for failed tests (failsafe plugin used)

Tags: junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have several tests cases in a list using failsafe and Junit as per below:

```
    @Test
    public void testResults() {
        for (TestCase test : TestCaseList) {
            int result = test.getActualResult();
            int expected = test.getExpectedResult();
                if (result != expected) {
                    System.out.println("Failed test " + test.getTestInfo());
                }
                assertEquals(result, expected);
        }
    }
```

I want the report something like :

```
Failed test <test description here>
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <4>
     but: was <2>
```

Instead of just:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <4>
     but: was <2>
```

Is there a way to do that with Junit or other framework?

Comment: What data do you want it to display?

Comment: Something like: "Failed test " + test.getTestInfo());

Comment: That doesn't explain what data you want. Give an example (in your question, not a comment) of the output you desire.

Comment: Added desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a message to the assert:

```
assertEquals(test.getTestInfo(), result, expected);
```

This creates the following report:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: <test description here>
  Expected: is <4>
       but: was <2>
```